# weird behavior of numba guvectorize

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I write a function to test numba.guvectorize.  This function takes product of two numpy arrays and compute the sum after first axis, as following:

```
from numba import guvectorize, float64
import numpy as np
@guvectorize([(float64[:], float64[:], float64)], '(n),(n)->()')
def g(x, y, res):
    res = np.sum(x * y)
```

However, the above guvectorize function returns wrong results as shown below:

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(3,4)
>>> b = np.random.randn(3,4)
>>> np.sum(a * b, axis=1)
array([-0.83053829, -0.15221319, -2.27825015])
>>> g(a, b)
array([4.67406747e-310, 0.00000000e+000, 1.58101007e-322])
```

What might be causing this problem?

Comment: In one case you pass `axis=1`, in the other you don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `g()` receives an uninitialized array through the `res` parameter. Assigning a new value to it doesn't modify the original array passed to the function.

You need to replace the contents of `res` (and declare it as an array):

```
@guvectorize([(float64[:], float64[:], float64[:])], '(n),(n)->()')
def g(x, y, res):
    res[:] = np.sum(x * y)
```

The function operates on 1D vectors and returns a scalar (thus the signature `(n),(n)->()`) and guvectorize does the job of dealing with 2D inputs and returning a 1D output.

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(3,4)
>>> b = np.random.randn(3,4)
>>> np.sum(a * b, axis=1)
array([-3.1756397 ,  5.72632531,  0.45359806])
>>> g(a, b)
array([-3.1756397 ,  5.72632531,  0.45359806])
```

But the original Numpy function `np.sum` is already vectorized and compiled, so there is little speed gain in using guvectorize in this specific case.

Answer (score -1):

Your `a` and `b` arrays are 2-dimensional, while your guvectorized function has signature of accepting 1D arrays and returning 0D scalar. You have to modify it to accept 2D and return 1D.

In one case you do `np.sum` with `axis = 1` in another case without it, you have to do same thing in both cases.

Also instead of `res = ...` use `res[...] = ...`. Maybe it is not the problem in case of guvectorize but it can be a general problem in Numpy code because you have to assign values instead of variable reference.

In my case I added `cache = True` param to guvectorize decorator, it only speeds up running through caching/re-using Numba compiled code and not re-compiling it on every run. It just speeds up things.

Full modified corrected code see below:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66608336#main.py)

```
from numba import guvectorize, float64
import numpy as np
@guvectorize([(float64[:, :], float64[:, :], float64[:])], '(n, m),(n, m)->(n)', cache = True)
def g(x, y, res):
    res[...] = np.sum(x * y, axis = 1)

# Test
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randn(3, 4)
b = np.random.randn(3, 4)
print(np.sum(a * b, axis = 1))
print(g(a, b))
```

Output:

```
[ 2.57335386  3.41749149 -0.42290296]
[ 2.57335386  3.41749149 -0.42290296]
```

Comment: The idea of vectorizing a function is to write code that works on smaller dimensions. If you write the same code that would do the job without the function, then the code works, but there's no vectorization.

Comment: @aerobiomat guvectorized function is just a regular Numba function as any other, the only difference is that it pre-creates input/output arrays for you with given signature. Everything that is inside any Numba function is compiled to optimized C++ code and then to machine code. So ANY Numba function will be boosted/speeded-up, in this sense any function is vectorized function. What is vectorization it is just speeding up working with arrays/vectors in ANY way. Any Numba function has speedup of `20x-200x` times compared to Python code, so any Numba function is a way to vectorize (speedup).

Comment: Not for code already vectorized and compiled. Check the timing yourself on large arrays.

Comment: @aerobiomat Your code in your answer will not give any improvement either in speed on large data. Because your code uses just Numpy functions same like mine. And numpy functions are already implemented in C/Cython code hence Numba will not give any improvement. If you use just numpy functions then there will be no improvement. But that is what OP's question was about to vectorize using Numpy functions.

Comment: @aerobiomat But I understood what you mean regarding how @guvectorize works. So it also does a job of gathering results. It calls same code of function-body many times to collect all `res` sub-results and composes it into final large array.

Comment: Well, the original problem was the function returning garbage, and that's what I tried to address in my answer.